# SQL date conversion changes time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a strange problem. I convert a date using the following

> CONVERT(varchar(64), table.[Date],
>   120) AS the_date

Now, the strange thig is that if I don't run the conversion the time is for example `2011-01-10 13:10:01` abut if I run the conversion the time will become `2011-01-10 13:10:02`. How can this be? I only run a conversion.

Update: The column is a `datetime` column. I have tried converting using `121` but same problem. If I list the unconverted value with the converted one side by side in `SQL Server Enterprise Manager` I get the difference on a row here and there. It seems `Enterprise Manager` also converts it when outputing it for viewing since if I fetch the data using PHP and don't convert I see that the column is saved like `Jan 10 2011  3:31PM`

Update: Running query analyzer I get

```
2011-01-05 10:49:48.557    2011-01-05 10:49:48
```

So that seems to have been the origin of the error. Haven't seen any errors while quickly looking through the result set now. Why can't the make aome software that works for once? :)

Comment: Are you running it a minute later?

Comment: Maybe the conversion says time = time+1; :D

Comment: Enterprise manager - there's your problem :-) In all seriousness, I'd never trust what Enterprise Manager gets up to behind the scenes. What happens if you run your query through query analyzer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query, run through query analyzer, or SSMS, returns the expected values:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(64),CONVERT(datetime,'2010-01-01T10:59:31.997'),120),CONVERT(datetime,'2010-01-01T10:59:31.997')

2010-01-01 10:59:31 2010-01-01 10:59:31.997
```

Running the same through Enterprise Manager yields:

```
2010-01-01 10:59:31 01/01/2010 10:59:32
```

That is, enterprise manager already applies formatting to datetime columns, rounds the output and hides milliseconds. It should not be trusted for, well, anything.

Comment: Good call. I forgot how rubbish EM is

Answer (score 2):

Rounding. There is probably a millisecond value there too.

Comment: I thought of this, but ran a test, and even if the date value ends with 997 milliseconds, I can't get SQL to round the seconds value up.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `convert()` rounding up the time?

There is info on rounding here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Show your problem  using

```
select table.[Date], CONVERT(varchar(64), table.[Date], 120) AS the_date from table
```

and it could be a conversion problem

Answer (score 0):

Use CONVERT(varchar(64), [Date], **121**) to preserve the milliseconds.